# Reducing the space between the sidebarpanel and mainpanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

[image]Kindly suggest me as how to reduce the space between the sidebarpanel and mainpanel in shiny app.

Regards,
Mohan

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you post the code R

Comment: @CClaire I have posted the code in the link below,      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792933/need-help-on-conditional-panel-in-shiny

Comment: @CClaire You are exactly right. But, in that case if i reduce the width of sidebarpanel there will be additional space created between the sidebarpanel and mainpanel. So, my question is.... Is there a way we can increase the width of the mainpanel of take away those empty spaces which have generated due to change isn the width of the sidebarpanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use column to choose the size of my dashboard. I think the problem is because you set the size in px in tags$style.
This code works

```
library(shiny)    
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
              #img(src='logo.jpg', align = "right"),
              titlePanel("Project1"),
              fluidRow(width=12,
              sidebarLayout(
                column(width=4,
                sidebarPanel(
                     width=12,
                     radioButtons("source", "Source Type:", c("online", "offline")),
                     conditionalPanel(
                       condition = "input.source == 'online'",
                       selectInput("e_source", "online_Source",
                                   list("Yahoo","CNBC","Others"), selected = "CNBC")),
                     conditionalPanel(
                       condition = "input.source == 'offline'",
                       selectInput("e_source", "offline_Source",
                                   list("Newspaper",
                                        "magazines",
                                        "books"), selected = "books")),
                     checkboxGroupInput("size", 
                                   label = ("aAd size"), 
                                   choices = list("Medium", "Large", "small"
                                   ), selected = "small"))),
                column(width=8,
                       mainPanel(tabsetPanel("tab",tabPanel("Ad Details", tableOutput("table1"))), width=12))
              ))))
```